# How do I find a file name that's exactly 8 levels deep?

Tags: shell-script, find

I'm using the 'find' command to search for files in a backup system. I want to find all file names containing a certain string (e.g. '*XYZ*') that are exactly 8 levels deep.

Is there a find syntax that will do this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using GNU `find` or another `find` which has these options,

```
find . -mindepth 8 -maxdepth 8 -name '*XYZ*'
```

If you don't have such a `find` command, you can use this POSIX version:

```
# must contain exactly 7 slashes
find . -path '*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*' -prune -name '*XYZ*'
```

`-path '*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*'` selects paths that are at least 8 levels deep (contain at least 7 slashes, depth 0 is `.` itself, depth 1 is the files in the current directory), doing `-prune` for them will prevent `find` from descending into those folders that are 8 levels deep, so the 9 and above ones will never be seen.

Comment: POSIXly, you can use `-path '*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*' -prune -name '*XYZ*'`. Note that some BSDs also have `-mindepth`/`-maxdepth` but also `-depth 8`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I added `-path '*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*'` but `-depth 8` does not make sense to me: it would conflict with the standard test `-depth` which does not take any argument.

Comment: How about `ls -l */*/*/*/*/*/*/*XZY*`?

Comment: @jimmij sure, but OP is specifically asking about `find`, maybe because they want to apply some additional tests that are fancier than `-name` or maybe because the number of potential matches would overflow command line arguments.

Comment: Thanks very much. Since it's a backup, there are many versions of the same folder. I realized what I actually want to do is run `find ./folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7/folder8 -name '*XYZ*' ` where the folder1 is variable, i.e. all the folders in the current directory, but folders2-8 have the same structure. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: About `-depth 8`. `8` (or any number) being not a valid find predicate, there's no confusion possible with the `-depth` standalone predicate.